# Async call in a TypeScript decorator

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, decorator

Sorry in advance for the long quest. I am trying to be as clear as possible with the issue that I am facing.

I have created a [decorators utils library](https://github.com/vlio20/utils-decorators) and I encountered a strange behaviour while working on one of the decorators (https://github.com/vlio20/utils-decorators/blob/master/src/after/after.ts).

The decorator is named "after" and it should execute a different function after the execution of the decorated method. But here is the thing, if the function is returning a promise the decorator should wait for it to be resolved and only then call the after func.

Here is relevant code:

```
        if (resolvedConfig.wait) {
          const response = await originalMethod.apply(this, args);
          afterFunc({
            args,
            response
          });
        } else {
          const response = originalMethod.apply(this, args);
          afterFunc({
            args,
            response
          });
        }
```

As you can see I am one providing a flag for the decorator to indicate that the decorated method is an async function and it returns a Promise. I would be happy to get read of this flag by having the following code:

```
        const response = await originalMethod.apply(this, args);
          afterFunc({
            args,
            response
          });
```

Basically, I want to always put `await` before the execution of the original method, as from my understanding in case of sync method the await doesn't do anything.

The problem is with that when I am changing the code as suggested above, the following unit test fails:

```
  it('should verify after method invocation when method is provided', () => {
    let counter = 0;

    const afterFunc = jest.fn(() => {
      expect(counter).toBe(1);
    });

    class T {

      @after<T, void>({
        func: afterFunc
      })
      foo(x: number): void {
        return this.goo(x);
      }

      goo(x: number): void {
        expect(counter++).toBe(0);

        return;
      }
    }

    const t = new T();
    const spyGoo = jest.spyOn(T.prototype, 'goo');

    t.foo(1);
    expect(spyGoo).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(spyGoo).toBeCalledWith(1);
    expect(afterFunc.mock.calls.length).toBe(1); // this line fails
  });
```

I have created a fork of the lib where this exact test is failing (https://github.com/vlio20/utils-decorators/pull/new/after-issue).

What is wrong with my perception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Basically, I want to always put await before the execution of the original method, as from my understanding in case of sync method the await doesn't do anything.

This is not true. [According to the AsyncFunction reference on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) (which itself directly references the ECMAScript spec), any function denoted as `async` will *always* have the function body execute out of the regular call sequence.

In other words, the callee does not matter to the async/await function, it will *always* resolve asynchronously. This is important as a function should ideally only [ever be synchronous or asynchronous](https://medium.com/@bluepnume/intentionally-unleashing-zalgo-with-promises-ab3f63ead2fd) and never both. This is enshrined in the return type of async functions: they will *always* yield a promise, regardless of what goes on inside of them, and promises can never be inspected synchronously.

The only way for you to accomplish this is to avoid using `await`/`async` altogether and inspect the return type of your function directly:

```
const after = ({ func }) => (f) => (..args) => {
  const value = f(...args)
  if ('then' in value === false) {
    func()
    return value 
  }

  return value.then(value => {
    func()
    return value
  })
}
```

As you can probably tell from the tone of this answer (and my references), I do not think that it is a good approach to do this. Keeping your functions wholly synchronous or asynchronous would be advisable.

Comment: Thanks Dan. So how can we explain that the following https://prnt.sc/r8pd5t yields a and then b?

Comment: you're using `await a()` and then `b()`. The top level console is wrapped in `async function()` in browsers that support top level `async`, so the execution order will be as you expect

Answer (score 1):

I hope this little code can help you:

```
a = async () => console.log(await 'a')
a()
console.log('b')
```

It will show b and only then a. Because if have `await` then async function will always execute a bit later and you need to wait for it. That's why all of your sync functions in the test worked fine and the last one async one did not.

If you will add `await` to `t.foo(1)` test should pass.

My opinion is that it's better to do separate implementations of `afterFunc`, luckily asyncness could be determined from `function.name`

Here is example closer to decorator problem:

```
let didDecoratorFinish = false

const decorator = (fn) => {
  return async (...args) => {
    await fn()
    didDecoratorFinish = true
  }
}

const test = () => {
  let fnWasCalled = false
  const fn = decorator(() => fnWasCalled = true)
  fn()
  console.log(fnWasCalled) // true
  console.log(didDecoratorFinish) // guess what =)
}
test()
```

Again, solution is or to use `await` in the test, or to make sync and async decorator implementation. For example (sorry, don't know typescript):

```
const afterFn = function(fn, afterFn) {
  // you can use is-async-function npm package for example
  if (isFunctionAsync(fn))
    return (...args) =>
      new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
          const result = await fn.apply(this, args)
          await afterFn() // I don't know if you want to wait for afterFn
          resolve(result)
        } catch (err) {
          reject(err)
        }
      })
  else
    return (...args) => {
      const result = fn.apply(this, args)
      afterFn() // it can be async, I don't know if you want to wait for it
      return result
    }
}
```

Comment: yo have await on the screenshot and not in the test

Comment: The await is in the decorator